# Why is my text-file being treated as a single string?

Tags: python-3.x, text-files

I have a text file with a lot of names which is separated by commas, and with each name in quotation marks. The textfile looks something like: "MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH","JENNIFER","MARIA","SUSAN","MARGARET","DOROTHY","LISA","NANCY","KAREN"

My problem is that when I try to iterate through this text file after I convert it to a list is that the entire textfile is being treated as a single string. 
The textfile ater converting it to a string looks like:
[['MARY', 'PATRICIA', 'LINDA', 'BARBARA', 'ELIZABETH', 'JENNIFER', 'MARIA', 'SUSAN', 'MARGARET', 'DOROTHY', 'LISA', 'NANCY', 'KAREN']]

The code I have tried to do this with is:

```py
import csv 

results = []
with open('p022_names.txt', newline='') as inputfile:
    for word in csv.reader(inputfile):
        results.append(word)

print(results)
```

when I do something like

```py
print(results[0])
```

it prints the entire text file, rather than just 'Mary' Thus how would I be able to iterate through each name individually rather than treating the entire thing as a single string.

Comment: So dude - did you figure it out?  Did the link/sample code help?

Comment: Yes thanks a lot man, code is now working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You failed to specify a delimiter.

Here's a complete example:

> https://realpython.com/python-csv/
>
> ```
> import csv
>
> with open('employee_birthday.txt') as csv_file:
>     csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
>     line_count = 0
>     for row in csv_reader:
>         if line_count == 0:
>             print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
>             line_count += 1
>         else:
>             print(f'\t{row[0]} works in the {row[1]} department, and was born in {row[2]}.')
>             line_count += 1
>     print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
> ```

In this example, you could access the individual "words" as `row[1]`, etc.